# How can I convert to date time with Posixct in r

Tags: r, datetime

I have this one column, where I collected the datas. It's important that evertyhing is in the same one column.

```
    date  

2020 1 12 14 57  
2020 1 12 14 58 
2020 1 12 14 59 
2020 1 12 15 0  
2020 1 12 15 1  
2020 1 12 15 2
```

How can I convert this to date time form like this: 2020-1-12 14:57
I tried this: `as.POSIXct(df$date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")`, but I got NA

Comment: please provide sample data using `dput()`.

Comment: probably: `as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%Y %m %d %H %M")`

Comment: Yes, in this way works, thank you!